# ListBoxItem animation and opacity

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, wpf-controls

I have a Listbox with styles, including Listboxitem with styles. I am trying to create an animation that changes opacity from 0 to 1, to make items show on the list. I've managed to do this with the following code:

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle1" TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF393C3F" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                        <Border Name="Border" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border Name="Border" Padding="10,1,0,0" Background="{x:Null}">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource arrow}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF828689" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="true">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

The thing works as it should (apart from that I want more time to pass between current and next item animation start. But it has a problem with opacity. Everything possible is set to transparent, backgrounds and all. And I use transparent .png brush for selected item.

The problem is with the opacity animation and is best seen on the bottom picture:

[image: Screenshot]

This is a screenshot in the middle of animation (at the time the opacity of the listboxitems is 0.8) and you can clearly see white background around all text. It's even more visible in the first selected item, because it uses transparent .png. This background magically dissapears when animation is finished and the opacity is 1.0.

How to fix this problem? Did I forget to set any background perhaps?

Thank you for your help!

Edit:

I am adding my listbox declaration:

```
<ListBox Height="239" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Background="{x:Null}"  FontWeight="Black" FontSize="8" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" BorderThickness="0" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle1}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{x:Null}" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Also another question is: How to delay the animation that each listboxitem would be displayed with a delay of few milliseconds before the next one?

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Can you add you list box declaration? I have plugged this style into one of my programs and don't have the issue you are having.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Scott. I have added you my listbox declaration. I've done some more testing and it is absolutely not system dependant. The problem is in my app or in WPF. There does not even need to be an animation for this problem. The second listbox item has opacity set in style that is different from 0 or 1.0, it renders with white background. Even the listbox items without background picture. The picture in my post is rendered at 0.8 opacity of the listbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem. The problem was that in code I was overriding window's AllowTransparency flag. Now it works as it should. If anyone would encounter a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a system dependent rendering anomaly, i tried that style (only had to use my own selected item image, also a transparent PNG) and it worked quite nicely.
In one application of mine images set to the `Fill` property of `Rectangle`s were weirdly stretched on one of my computers (which even had the same operating system, Win7 Professional) so that would not be unheard of...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I dont think you're right, since it renders the same on multiple computers. I think it's an WPF issue, the thing that causes it, is probably part of another style/template, not this one.


As soon as I opacity different from 0 or 1, I get white background with items. Just the way it looks on the picture I posted. Try putting a fill for background in your app and let me know if it's working. Regards.

Comment: Try to put a background in that is a shade of white, such as #DDDDDD (I was using #FAF6F9).